# Audio from headphones very low with Pulseaudio

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

So i got a problem with using my headphones jack on my Laptop. The speaker works fine.

My problem is that when i play audio at a decent level on my speakers and then put in my earphones or headphone in my headphone jack. The sound is very low and when i turn it up with my fn Keys the sound get distorted. So when the audio is distorted and i unplug my headphones, the speaker audio is nearly speaker breaking high.

i tried going through the Pulseaudio gui settings, deleting the config file and rebooting. Deleting the package and re installing but nothing so far worked.

In here are my GUI settings of Pulseaudio.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0VGL.jpg

Thank you.

**SOLVED**

Comment: It looks (to me) like you have uploaded the same image three times. What am I missing? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Search more, this question keeps coming up here all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i had to do it so to install and do 
alsamixer -c0
(or )
alsamixer -c1

And then move the headphones bar to 100% it was all the way down in my case.
Information from:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/arch-distorted-sound-while-using-headset-4175610373/